# New top bar is missing features/generally unintuitive

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar

The new top bar is very unintuitive.
Sure it works for all of us, because we're used to SO, but new users will be extremely confused by this new, less featured design.

New additions should add features, or remove unwarranted/deprecated features.
This addition has removed many useful features, does not match the site layout *at all*, and is absolutely sure to increase the number of confused new users.

IMHO it should have many many more features in all of the empty unused space, not less. Use the space you have to your advantage.

EDIT: This is *not* a duplicate, we were specifically told to start *new* questions with the [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar) tag in the original Meta post. Which is what I have done.

Comment: Personal note from me: please move the chat link back to where it was!

Comment: That is your own opinion. If you hate it then just contribute something. Don't just blatantly say "I hate it"

Comment: New users would see this as their normal. Old users are the ones confused by change

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA that's exactly what he's doing - discussing it here in meta. Not very gracefully but saying "Cool Story Bro" seems rather moot imo. He dislikes something so he came here to talk about it - this is how this site works. The only complaint is - where was he when it was discussed extensively in meta this last month.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA If you would kindly link me to the repo I will gladly submit a PR with changes... Oh wait.

Comment: @random I'm not confused by it. It's legitimately unintuitive when you remove all text from a menu bar that has ample room for said text. Little, uninformative buttons are a bad trend forming in the world of technology.

Comment: Yes. That simplified, metro interfaced task bar with 3 buttons or so is very, very unintuitive.

Comment: @Jhawins - I didn't downvote you, but many who downvote you might be doing so because of the existence of a previous thread (linked above) that discussed issues with the new top bar, extensively. I don't see how that's fair, though, since only users who frequent meta would have seen that thread, and others didn't get a chance to participate—and even users who only visit SO (not meta) should have a say. I think there should be a new thread like the previous one, community wiki'd, pertaining to the _released_ top bar (as opposed to the "beta").

Comment: I'm not worried about downvotes. No problem. I just want to point out that small uninformative buttons are a bad thing. We shouldn't be moving backwards, which is what the new top bar is, a step backwards.

Comment: I have to agree, I'm not very good at multitasking my accounts (I didn't even know what meta was until a couple weeks ago), yet I had no knowledge on SO that the header would change (personally, I don't care, but I'm just saying I've been online almost everyday for the past 3 months and I heard nothing of it until today)

Comment: How is the menu unintuitive because it doesn't use all available real estate?  Sites that try to fill up every bit of space with links to something or another are the ones that tend to be more unintuitive; you can't find the links that are really important through all of the clutter.  Content that was actually used frequently is now more prominent; links that tended to not be used much were either removed, or are an extra click away.  That greatly improves usability for new users; it is only really an issue for people used to the old system who just need to get used to something new.

Comment: @Servy You've missed the point. The fact that there is more room to be used is a secondary point, but not the main point I'm making. Aside from that, nothing has been gained from removing the other features, the *only* thing that's happened is we lost features. Removing features for no benefit is silly.

Comment: @Jhawins Now that we got your point, what feature is missing exactly ?

Comment: Disagree. I like it, except the location of the logout button I think it is a great improvement. People always fear and loathe change; otherwise, it wouldn't be so hard to get things done. Buck up: in another month, you'll be off complaining about the new Facebook wall and saying, "What new StackExchange nav bar?"

Comment: @Jhawins That comment makes it pretty clear to me that you just aren't used to it yet.  There are actually several features that were added, some moved, and others removed entirely.  I suggest you take some time to get used to it; find out where some of the moved items were moved to, discover some of the new features, etc., and then consider providing some feedback.  If/when you do make that decision, you should really make an effort to make your post more constructive; it will greatly improve it's reception by others.

Comment: This is what it looks like for a moderator: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wkuDU.png

Comment: @random So I only need to become a mod to get a purple bunny(?) in my top nav bar.  I guess I'll have to run for the next election now.

Comment: @random that outlines the problem better. Now I can understand why it's been changed, but come on, what percentage of users are moderators? The global bar shouldn't be tailored to fit your needs when the vast majority of users aren't like you. Wouldn't it make more sense to design a sleek yet *also* intuitive top bar for the public, and then a work horse top bar for the mods?

Comment: I want to continue this discussion, but I'm afraid the real world is calling for me. I'll try to check back in tonight. The point of this post is to raise a healthy discussion about this, so please, future posters, keep that in mind.

Comment: @Jhawins Please bring back some arguments from the real world. I'd love to know what those missing features are.

Comment: "Sleek" is not cluttering things up. It's trimming down things to the most first used actions when not logged in, then adding items as necessary for regular users.

Comment: 19 votes and it's still hanging between -2 and +2. Seems to be a perfect split, which shows that (if this continues) it is worth considering giving users the option to choose between either bar.

Comment: @random I agree with that statement. Maybe the real solution is to (in the future) make this bar customizable, maybe not. I'm not saying one way is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: @Jhawins Either that or people just aren't used to it, and when it's been more than a few hours since the feature's release and people figure it out, they won't see a need for (major overhauling) changes.  When you start talking about customization it opens up a pretty big can of worms.  That adds a *lot* of complexity, you need to deal with users who mess up/change a setting by accident, it makes support harder as you don't *know* what any given person's settings are, etc.

Comment: @Servy this isn't a major overhauling change. This is an incredibly simple change.

Comment: @Jhawins `This is an incredibly simple change` .. according to who ? Also might I re-ask what the missing features are ? With such a promising title, I expected a little content.

Comment: @Jhawins Well, technically, you haven't really proposed *any* change, so I guess I (and every but you) don't know what you want (which is part of the problem).  If you just want it to go back to what it was before, I consider it a pretty big change.  It got a more or less full overhaul.  If you don't want that, then you'll need to clarify your request.

Comment: @Servy This question is clearly tagged as a discussion. You obviously don't understand basic HTML/CSS if you would consider this a major change.

Comment: @Jhawins I've actually asked 3 times what the missing features are. I still didn't have an answer. Still no answers. Maybe there a no missing features ? Maybe there are.. You didn't specify anything in your question which makes this discussion totally meaningless.

Comment: Users that didn't create their accounts in the last 3 hours know exactly what features are missing. You don't need to ask, which is why I wanted to avoid a long comment thread explaining common knowledge.

Comment: @Servy no one said the site was unintuitive, just the top bar is less intuitive than before. (Please Google the word as you seem to think it means something similar to "unuseable" and no one used the word "unusable" at all. Please stop trying to derail this thread.

Comment: @Jhawins Can you please develop ? I created my account almost 2 years ago and I don't see the missing features.

Comment: @Jhawins Also, On-Rail threads rarely have 4 closing votes.

Comment: @Jhawins *Off topic* I googled dense ((of a person) stupid.) and it's a bit offensive. Anyway that's not the point. Can you please tell me what features are missing ?

Comment: @Jhawins So you think that every single think that was removed should be added back in?  If you're expecting us to go off of our knowledge of what was there before then that would imply that you don't think anything should have been removed at all, and that there weren't any items that were simply not adding value.  If that's the case, I strongly disagree; a number of the items weren't really useful.  If you only really want back a subset of what was removed, we need to know what you want added back.  Your repeated refusal to describe what you feel is now "missing" is preventing discussion.

Comment: I thought it was less intuitive when the beta was rolled out a month ago here. It took about an hour or so to realize I was wrong, and within a week or so I was thinking "I wonder when they'll roll this out to SO?". I was pleasantly surprised to see it show up today. There has been a public beta here at Meta over the past month, and here is where changes to features are usually announced. If you want a chance to participate in providing feedback on upcoming changes, you should check in here more often. :-)

Comment: I can't understand how a solid black bar is "intuitive".  Nearly a third of the bar is solid black with no text, no icons, no nothing.  The hover menu is gone, while the user name can only be seen if you hover over that quilt-like thingie.  Why does reputation changes merit a button of its own when there's no way at all to logout (that I can see)?

Comment: @Chris - Where is this supposed logout button?

Comment: And once you're in Meta, how do you return to the main board?

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger Am assuming you figured it out by now, but, the answer to both queries is the same: in the StackExchange drop-down at the left of the navigation bar. There are links to all the sites, as well as the logout button. There's a thread about the logout button here if you want to comment on that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement/

Comment: Well, regardless, the thing is still as ugly as sin.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger [Looky here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210012/would-it-be-possible-to-lighten-the-color-of-the-new-top-bar/210119#210119)

Comment: Out of 32 votes now there is still an even split. Worth noting.

Answer (score 7):

Issues with new bar:

- It now takes two clicks to get to reputation, clicking on reputation number should still allow you to access more specific information.
- It doesn't allow filtering of categories of information in the inbox.  This makes it hard to navigate if very active.  There should be filter options provided when it expands.
- Inbox records are too narrow and each individual item is too tall.  Not enough information can be displayed on the screen at a time for the inbox which makes it very difficult to check on what activity has occurred since I was last on.  There should be an option to condense the Inbox text or to resize the amount of space it uses when open.
- Accessing meta and chat should not require two clicks, these should at least optionally be able to be put back on the bar, particularly since there is a ton of unused space on the bar.
- Reputation drop down is an interesting idea, however an option to sort or filter it by site would greatly increase the usefulness.  Having my reputation intermixed based on when exactly it arrived isn't really helpful.

On the good side:

- The ability to easily switch between sites from the StackExchange drop down is great.

Overall, the new bar feels like it lacks a lot of polish and doesn't feel like a lot of thought went into its design.  It is clearly going for a very minimalist feel, however, in doing so it increased the difficulty of use and made it less intuitive.  Simplistic interfaces are only helpful if they are simple to use and the new bar is anything but.  It did make one very nice and sorely needed improvement, but overall the cost of all the lost functionality makes it a strong net negative.

Comment: There has always been the ability to switch between sites using the StackExchange dropdown. :P
Thank you for adding to this discussion with your own personal opinion.

Comment: @Jhawins - sure, through all sites, but it now groups the sites you actually use.  Before it was always easier for me to simply type the URL or go through my profile page.

Comment: Sweet. I hadn't seen this option. I agree there are good things about it as well. What I suggest is honestly giving the user an option, because we all love options, and it's non-invasive to the rest of the sites functionality. The only thing adding an option would do is give us the option, no downfall.

Comment: Yeah, visually it isn't bad, it just needs more polish and options.

Comment: It's one click to meta if you scroll to the footer. Not everything needs to be loaded into the header.

Comment: @Random - yes, because scrolling all the way to the footer is so much easier than making two clicks at the top of the page.  Footers are near useless when you have 20 to 30 questions to a page.

Comment: Hit the **End** key and you're there at the bottom of the page

Comment: @Random - still two clicks then and with different things.  Still not as easy and still harder than clicking twice on the header.

Comment: @AJHenderson The old "All Sites" list put the sites where you've earned rep. at the top, so yeah, it grouped them as well...  Other than that, I pretty much agree with everything here.  Some of it is easily fixable with userscripts/user styles, but not all.

Answer (score 4):

If your *question* is not a complaint then it must be seeking a discussion. I think the new users will see the new toolbar as something really cool. I remember when I first joined Stack Overflow. There have been multiple features that required me to dig a bit deeper to get to know them. Trust me, there still are a few bits here and there which seem new to me.

The point is that new users will not know the old bar, they won't know the difference  - so they're left with nothing to compare to (*except a few screenshots on meta, not the point though*). People who visit Stack Overflow not so frequently will be the ones that are confused by the *new look*.

This has been discussed multiple times and first was applied on meta about 2/3 weeks ago. There was a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta?rq=1) about the new toolbar, which is the reason why some people may consider your enquiry as a *duplicate.*

If I could give you one advice, please have some backing arguments next time you want to discuss something - do not just throw a "I HATE IT!" on us without any sensible/constructive reasoning.

Comment: I am seeking discussion for sure. Also, the comment of hating it was removed.

Comment: Cool, maybe, whatever. But it's missing **features**. Also, suggesting to contribute to a locked thread is not constructive.

Comment: Jhawins, you seem to be complaining but not being objective and not demonstrating your opinion constructively. If I were you I would spend a few minutes going reading a few highly upvoted questions on meta to get a *feel* for **meta**. @Gilles, please point them out.

Comment: @mehow I and others did in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta

Comment: @Gilles yes you're right. But look on the right hand side and see *milion* of related questions

Comment: @Gilles I did not read every single answer in there... I am not sure you'll find one person who read it all

Comment: @mehow read the original question please. It clearly states to open *new* questions with comments or concerns, which is why I did so instead of participating normally in that thread like usual.

Comment: For the record: the original question is now *locked*. You can no longer discuss things there. At the top it states: **EDIT Dec 4 - We're doing it live! Please post bugs or concerns as questions tagged `[top-bar]`**

Comment: @mehow I'd expect some of the SE employee's to have read it all.  There isn't much point in asking a community for feedback if you're not going to look through it.  I wouldn't expect most casual readers to read through the whole thing though, of course.

Comment: well, in the UK, last time I checked I was still at work. It was more than 3 hours ago and the post just got locked 3 hours ago so this is why I didn't realize it was locked!

Comment: @Mehow no one is responsible for you not knowing but yourself. It was posted multiple times before you put this up.

Comment: @Jhawins alright alright just calm down bud