# Add a logout link to the user profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, usability, logout

On most sites that require logging in, the logout functionality is accessed by clicking your user name or some variation thereof, when it isn't a direct link (usually in a header).

With the old top bar, there was a “log out” link in the box that appeared when hovering on your user name. That's exactly where you'd expect to find it.

Now, the logout link is… Did you find it? It's hidden in the list of sites. There's “chat”, “blog”, and “log out”. One of these links is not like the others, and indeed is entirely unlike anything in that menu.

Since clicking on the username now brings the profile page (which makes perfect sense), the logout link should be on the profile page.

The profile page is a logical place to put a logout link anyway, regardless of how you get to it.

Comment: There's another thread about this subject.... why not add to that one instead? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement

Comment: @Chris Because I hadn't found it in the flurry of top bar feature requests. Thanks for pointing it out. I don't think it's quite the same request though — I'd expect a logout link on the profile page, regardless of how else it's available.

Comment: Fair enough. FWIW, I completely agree with this too. The run of links on the upper-right-ish part of the screen would be a good place: "edit preferences flair apps my logins | network profile | logout"