# How do I log out?

Tags: support, logout

How do I log out of Stack Exchange?

I want to register as a new user so that people that know my username can't track me on the Internet. But how do I log out so I can register under a new name?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/logout - does that not work for you? It is linked in the sites drop down (top left of the page)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement

Comment: @Oded:  Not as of 15 December 2017 it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Stack Exchange button > log out

Comment: Best I can tell, this answer no longer conforms to the present site design, as of 15 December 2017.