# New top bar missing privileges, also chat/log out placement is illogical

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

The new top bar looks like a good improvement, but I think that at least the log out button and also the chat could return to a more prevalent place. Another thing that bothers me is that the quick link to privileges seems to have been removed. I kind of liked clicking on myself in the bar to see my recent reputation and such, although the new reputation looks cool. It does however get confusing with other sites being mixed in.

I'm sure we will all adapt to it pretty quickly, but please consider changing the position of some links, like moving chat, blog, and log out back to the bar itself. Thanks!

Comment: Discussion regarding the logout button: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I'll contribute

Comment: So... what about privileges? digging in help is odd and not very discoverable. why doesn't the reputation tab at least link to the help topic?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: Help->Help Center, click "View a list of privileges you can earn" under the Privileges section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember if this is a new change but there is a privileges link on your own profile page:

> [image]

Or you can simply add: `/help/privileges` to any SE site you visit, if you're looking for your current privileges. Example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Personally I think a link on one own profile page is more then enough. It's not exactly something the general population uses daily, if not weekly and It's more of quick check and leave.

As a Stack Exchange employee, Hynes ♦, has said on [other *so-called* missing items question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/stackexchange-drop-down-hiding-chat-blog-and-log-out-concerns/210085#comment672878_209971), "It's a feature used sometimes, so why should it be given "every time" placement?". Which in this case, I agree with.

Comment: For the record, Hynes is not really a moderator he's Stack Exchange employee (working on Careers site) who got diamond as part of his job. I doubt we'll see him moderating the site. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer