# How do I find the privileges I have earned and will earn in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

It used to be off the top bar, now its gone

Where has it moved?

**EDIT:  It moved onto the profile page !**

Right side same row as your name in profile:

http://picpaste.com/extpics/priv-3pxo1h9L.jpg

Thank you

Comment: Whether it's asking about SO's or MSO's top bar, they're the same top bar now. And the search target will allow people to be pointed toward the original. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- On the topbar -- <kbd>Help▼</kbd> > [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

  > [image]

  Then click [**privileges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

  > [image]
- Or click on [**privileges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) in your profile:

  > [image]

Comment: This used to be linked from the user-reputation hovertext. Does anyone know if this was an intentional change, or if it was just a functional regression in the new skin?

Comment: @RobStarling It was intentional. [See this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209988/how-to-get-my-hover-menu-back).. people are requesting it back, but I don't think it will be making a return.

Comment: it's clear that the hover-menu's disappearance was intentional; i just wonder if they realized that some links were pretty much only there.

Comment: @RobStarling This has some relevance http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210014/new-top-bar-missing-privileges-also-chat-log-out-placement-is-illogical