# Not able to see links to chat, logout, or privileges

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar

Today I open my SO account like I always do. But the UI of menus has changed. I am not able to see the chat tab, the logout link or the privileges link. Are they missing or moved somewhere else?

Changed UI:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"chat" and "log out" links are moved to the Multicollider SuperDropdown. You can now access it from there:

[image]

Privilege pages are linked in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help). See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210067/187824) for detailed information.

However, If you have better place for these links, you can share your idea [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209971/187824)

Comment: and where to see privileges?

Comment: @SomnathKharat In the [help].

Comment: @SomnathKharat help > privileges

Comment: no more the right response. :(